# How to get previous and next entry using the native GraphQL API?

Tags: craft3, query, graphql

How do I turn these Craft queries into a GraphQL one?

```
// entry.twig

entry.getPrev({ section: "contentHub" })
entry.getNext({ section: "contentHub" })
```

I want to get the previous and next entry using the current entry

Answer (score 3):

So I'm wondering the same thing, I'm using CraftQL as I need to support mutations, and I am close with this - but I get an error if I try to use $id instead of a hard-wired Int (e.g. 99):

```
query getEntryData($id: [Int]) {
  prevEntry: entry(prevSiblingOf: 99) {
    id
    title
    slug
    uri
  }
  nextEntry: entry(nextSiblingOf: 99) {
    id
    title
    slug
    uri
  }
  entryData: entry(section: investigations, id: $id) {
    id
    title
    slug
    uri
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
"message": "Variable \"$id\" of type \"[Int]\" used in position expecting type \"Int\".",
```

BUT then if I pass the $id as Int (and not [Int]) it works. Can't explain the typing difference.

```
query getEntryData($id: [Int], $sameId: Int) {

   prev:entry(prevSiblingOf: $sameId) {
    id
    title
    slug
    uri
  }
  next: entry(nextSiblingOf: $sameId) {
    id
    title
    slug
    uri
  }
  investigation: entry(section: investigations, id: $id) {
    id
    title
    slug
    uri
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@littered

your example is working when you unwrap the Int param in your query. This should work:

```
query getEntryData($id: Int) {
  prevEntry: entry(prevSiblingOf: $id) {
    id
    title
    slug
    uri
  }
  nextEntry: entry(nextSiblingOf: $id) {
    id
    title
    slug
    uri
  }
  entryData: entry(section: investigations, id: [$id]) {
    id
    title
    slug
    uri
  }
}
```

the id field in `entryData` is expecting a `QueryArgument` of type [Int] but prevSiblingOf/nextSiblingOf expect an Int. With the above fix you submit a integer and wrap it for the `entryData` in an Array.